# php mail breaks when trying to send the word "localhost" in email body - so weird

Tags: php, html, email, webforms, sendmail

I've got a php mail form that buyers fill out to send an email to a seller. Everything works fine, except that I'm testing it on my localhost MAMP server.

Problem: $message1 (the email body) comes from a $_POST['textarea']. If there is the url "http://localhost" sent through the form text area (placed in the email body), then the dang email never gets delivered. http://www.anythingelse.com works fine....I'm quite perplexed. Is there some safety feature that disables localhost urls being sent through a form?

If there are any other glaring errors in my code, any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Daniel

```
public function saleRequest($seller_email, $seller_username, $buyer_email, $buyer_username, $book_title, $subject1, $message1) {


    define("NAME","xxxxxxx");
    define("FROM",$buyer_email);

    $subject = substr_replace($subject1, '', 30);

    // -=-=-=-=- MAIL HEADERS

    $mime_boundary = md5(time()); 
    $headers = "From: ".NAME." <".FROM.">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\";\n\n"; 

    // -=-=-=-=- TEXT EMAIL PART

    $message = "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"; 
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n"; 

    $message .= wordwrap(stripslashes($message1), 30, PHP_EOL)."\n";

    // -=-=-=-=- HTML EMAIL PART

    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n"; 
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n"; 
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n"; 

    $message1 = $message1."this is html";

    $message .= nl2br(wordwrap(stripslashes($message1), 30, "<br>"))."<br>\n";

    // -=-=-=-=- FINAL BOUNDARY

    $message .= "--$mime_boundary--\n\n";
    unset($mime_boundary);
    return mail($seller_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

Comment: Anything showing up in your mail server's log as to why the mail's not being delivered? Or perhaps you've got something like suhosin running and it's doing url-filtering on form data? As well, don't built your own mime mails. it's far easier to use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer and let them do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a spam filter. It makes sense for most SMTP servers to filter out mail containing localhost URLs.

Check the headers of one of the working messages. Look which servers it have passed through (`Received` lines) and ask the sysadmins of those servers, or even better: configure your mail server to deliver all test mails locally and don't send them through any third party. That way you have control over the environment. If you already have control over all the mail servers involved, check their log files.

Comment: Huh? Why would a server filter out `localhost` URLs?

Comment: SLaks, why would anybody send a localhost URL in an e-mail in the first place? I can see worms using links to localhost to exploit flaws in services running on the computer.

Comment: When working together on a local copy of a website.  However, I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some safety feature that disables localhost urls being sent through a form?

**No.** At least not within PHP. Might be a mailserver issue, but that's to check with every MTA.